# Webpack displays version rather than running code - Windows 7

Tags: javascript, webpack

I realise this question is a little out there and not very informative, but the webpack code runs perfectly on linux based systems.

Simply, the script takes an `env` variable which is a folder name (contains the js to be compiled), then compiles each of the js files inside this given folder. Creates some js from this, then passes that down to `compile.js` once `webpack` has finished its business.

**package.json**

```
"start_windows": "set BABEL_ENV=development/client&&npm run clean && webpack --watch",
```

I am most surprised that line 14 of webpack does not run  `console.info("sdhfjkzhsdkfhzsdjkfh================",env);`

**webpack.base.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const getEntries = require("./scripts/build/getEntries");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const WebpackShellPlugin = require("webpack-shell-plugin");
const envGenerator = require("./scripts/build/handleEnv");
const LiveReloadPlugin = require("webpack-livereload-plugin");
console.info("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
/**
 * Webpack config
 */
module.exports = function() {
  const optionsReload = {};
  const env = envGenerator(process.env.npm_config_argv);
console.info("sdhfjkzhsdkfhzsdjkfh================",env);
  return {
    entry: getEntries(env),
    plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      debug: true
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("[name]/styles.css"),
    new LiveReloadPlugin(optionsReload),
    new WebpackShellPlugin({
      onBuildEnd: ["node ./scripts/build/compile.js"],
      dev: false // Allows script to run more than once (i.e on every watch)
    })
    ],
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "babel-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: "style-loader",
            use: ["css-loader", "postcss-loader", "sass-loader"]
          })
        }
      ]
    },
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
      publicPath: "/dist/",
      filename: "[name]/script.js"
    }
  };
};
```

**cygwin**

```
shruti@ASGLH-WL-12111 /cygdrive/c/Source/asos-mvt-framework
$ npm run build -- -env T1106-premier-upsell

> mvt-framework@0.0.2 build C:\Source\asos-mvt-framework
> npm run clean && webpack -p "-env" "T1106-premier-upsell"

npm WARN invalid config loglevel="notice"

> mvt-framework@0.0.2 clean C:\Source\asos-mvt-framework
> rm -rf ./dist/*

3.8.1 //output here where webpack should be running

> mvt-framework@0.0.2 postbuild C:\Source\asos-mvt-framework
> node ./scripts/build/compile.js

C:\Source\asos-mvt-framework\dist []
```

**getEntries.js**

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
// Directory where our Multi Variant Tests reside
const mvtFolderPath = path.resolve("./src/tests");

/**
 * Loop through the JS files in the test folder root
 * and define a new bundle for each one
 */
module.exports = function(testFolderName) {console.info(testFolderName);
  const entries = {};
  const testFolderPath = path.resolve(mvtFolderPath, testFolderName);

  fs.readdirSync(testFolderPath).forEach(file => {
    const fileName = path.parse(file).name;
    const fileExt = path.parse(file).ext;

    if (fileExt === ".js") {
      entries[fileName] = path.resolve(testFolderPath, file);
    }
  });

  return entries;
};
```

**handleEnv.js**

```
module.exports = function(env) {
  console.info(env);
  const envCooked = JSON.parse(env).cooked;

  if (envCooked.length === 1) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.error("\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m", "ERROR: Please supply a test folder");
    console.error(
      "\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m",
      "For Example: `npm start T9999-somme-test`"
    );
    console.info(`
    No env given
    `);
    process.exit();
  }

  return envCooked[3].substr(0, 1) === "T" ? envCooked[3] : envCooked[4];
};
```

Comment: Can you remove the second argument `env` from console and see if it gives any output at all ?

Comment: Thanks @rach8garg however, the console log will always fire. But I have removed the `sdhfjkzhsdkfhzsdjkfh================` from the console and still the same outcome.

Comment: So nothing is being printed ?

Comment: Yes, nothing is being printed at all. Except the version number of webpack which is 3.8.1

Comment: It looks like your `npm run...` is calling `npm run clean....` with different arguments (i.e. "env" doesn't look right, should be `--env` like in your `npm run...` command) What do the rest of your package.json scripts look like?